# Выход из одного цикла

Tags: python

Есть 3 файла, 2 из них сравнивают строки внутри, в третий файл записывается информация, в зависимости от проверки на вхождение.

```
f1 = open('text1.txt')
f2 = open('text2.txt')
f = open('over.txt', 'a')

for line1 in f1.readlines():
    for line2 in f2.readlines():
        if line1 in line2:
            f.write(line1)
            break
        elif line1 not in line2:
            f.write(line1)
        elif line2 not in line1:
            f.write(line2)

f.close()
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Если выставляю `break` в первый `if`, то получаю выход к первому `for` и во второй `for` цикл больше не входит. Как лучше сделать чтобы цикл второй запускался?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `readlines` считывает все строки из файла и позиция чтения после этого метода устанавливается в конец файла, поэтому следующий вызов `readlines` возвращает пустой список. Решений может быть несколько.

---

***Решение 1.***

Повторно открывать второй файл на каждой итерации первого цикла:

```
f1 = open('text1.txt')
f = open('over.txt', 'a')

for line1 in f1.readlines():
    f2 = open('text2.txt')           # <<<---
    for line2 in f2.readlines():
        if line1 in line2:
            f.write(line1)
            break
        elif line1 not in line2:
            f.write(line1)
        elif line2 not in line1:
            f.write(line2)
    f2.close()                       # <<<---

f.close()
f1.close()
```

---

***Решение 2.***

Считать все строки второго файла в переменную и читать во втором цикле именно её:

```
f1 = open('text1.txt')
f = open('over.txt', 'a')

f2 = open('text2.txt')
lines2 = f2.readlines()               # <<<---
f2.close()

for line1 in f1.readlines():
    for line2 in lines2:              # <<<---
        if line1 in line2:
            f.write(line1)
            break
        elif line1 not in line2:
            f.write(line1)
        elif line2 not in line1:
            f.write(line2)

f.close()
f1.close()
```

---

***Решение 3.***
Использовать метод `seek`, который переместит позицию чтения:

```
f1 = open('text1.txt')
f2 = open('text2.txt')
f = open('over.txt', 'a')

for line1 in f1.readlines():
    f2.seek(0)                       # <<<---
    for line2 in f2.readlines():
        if line1 in line2:
            f.write(line1)
            break
        elif line1 not in line2:
            f.write(line1)
        elif line2 not in line1:
            f.write(line2)

f.close()
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

---

---

А вот самое эффективное решение, которое гораздо экономнее относится к ресурсам:

```
f1 = open('text1.txt')
f2 = open('text2.txt')
f = open('over.txt', 'a')

for line1 in f1:                # <<<---
    f2.seek(0)                  # <<<---
    for line2 in f2:            # <<<---
        if line1 in line2:
            f.write(line1)
            break
        elif line1 not in line2:
            f.write(line1)
        elif line2 not in line1:
            f.write(line2)

f.close()
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Здесь вместо метода `readlines`, считывающего файл целиком будет использоваться итератор, считывающий файл построчно по мере необходимости.